# How can I add google recaptcha 3 on vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, recaptcha, vuetify.js, react-google-recaptcha

I want to add google recaptcha 3 in my vuetify project

The google recaptcha 3 like this :

[image]

I get reference from here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha-v3

First : I run `npm install vue-recaptcha-v3`

Second : I modify my main.js like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import { VueReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueReCaptcha, {
  siteKey: '<site key>',
  loaderOptions: {
    useRecaptchaNet: true
  }
})

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  methods: {
    recaptcha() {
      this.$recaptcha('login').then((token) => {
        console.log(token) // Will print the token
      })
    }
  },
  template: '<button @click="recaptcha">Execute recaptcha</button>'
}).$mount('#app')
```

My problem is i am confused to call it from my component

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    ...
        <v-row>
          <v-col
            cols="6"
          >
            <v-form v-model="valid" ref="form" 
            >
              <v-text-field
              label="Full Name"
              outlined
              v-model="fullname"
              ></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field
              label="Email"
              outlined
              v-model="email"
              ></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field
              label="Phone"
              outlined
              v-model="phone"
              ></v-text-field>

              <v-row justify="center">
                <v-btn color="green accent-4" :dark="valid" @click="validate()" :disabled="!valid">Save
                  <v-icon dark right>mdi-checkbox-marked-circle</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-row>
            </v-form>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      ...
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({

    })
  }
</script>
```

How can I call google recaptcha 3 from my component?

Answer (score 4):

You get two token from admin console when a site is added.

Use client secret in the Vue application and the server secret in the backend

> Add client secret in the main.js

```
Vue.use(VueReCaptcha, {
  siteKey: '<site key>'
}
```

> Remove the method in main.js, that is just for demo purpose

```
new Vue({,
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Add recaptcha on any events**

> In your Vue component add recaptcha

```
<template>
 <button @click="recaptcha">Recaptcha</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   ...
   methods: {
   ...
   recaptcha() {
      this.$recaptcha('login').then((token) => {
        console.log(token) // Will print the token
      })
    }
   },
   ....
  }
</script>
```

It returns the login token, you can use this to send post request to [recaptcha to verify the user](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)